# SQL Server : sum, groupby and many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I'm using SQL Server and in one query I need to select many columns as well as get a sum of certain column from the joined table. The second table has multiple records (1:N relationship).

However, as I used to do in mysql, here I can't seem to put just 1 main column in `group by` and I don't see why I need to put 20 columns there!

Is there a way to achieve it?

For example:

```
SELECT x, z, s, r, t, m, r, e, w, t, erm, w, we, wmw, wm, sum(t2.ee)
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.fk
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Many of these columns are btw calculations and are not even direct column names.

Comment: What MySQL allowed you to do here _violated the ansi standard_. Literally no other database allowed it, because it was _dangerous_ and could produce unexpected data.

Comment: Well, actually MySQL also allows this kind of heinous violation of GROUP BY. Doesnt' make it less heinous.

Comment: Its `dangerous` only if you dont understand what you are doing..

Comment: in fact, its more dangerous if you use multiple columns in group by and are expecting something else. For example, a table with cols (PKey, ID, Type) and has many records due to Type per ID. If the Type field is insignificant for a particular query, `group by ID` and `group By ID, Type` will generate different results and now this is more dangerous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the data, perhaps the window functions may help here.  Notice no need to group by

```
SELECT DISTINCT x,z,s,r,t,m,r,e,w,t,erm,w,we,wmw,wm
      ,sum(t2.ee) over (Partition By T1.ID)
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.fk
```

As discussed, another option could be

```
SELECT max(x),max(z),max(s),max(r),max(t),max(m),max(r),max(e),max(w),max(t),max(erm),max(w),max(we),max(wmw),max(wm),sum(t2.ee)
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.fk
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this and looks good. Coming from MySQL in not familiar with `over`, will this generate same results as `group by`?

Comment: @RaheelHasan  Happy to help.  Change is always hard, but I'm sure you will discover some things you like better in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Is `Over with partition by` more efficient than `group by`? I read the details of Over and it says it created a window on the results set. So it means query was executed, all rows were fetched and then results were calculated. So it looks like less efficient

Comment: @RaheelHasan My immediate guess would be no.  But depending on your data the delta may be nominal.  For example, I just tested on some sample data 166K rows 680 id's and the over was 20ms slower

Comment: @RaheelHasan another option would be to keep you Group By and wrap your non-group-by fields in a max()  i.e. max(x),max(z)...max(wm),sum(td2.ee)

Comment: right, thanks for doing that. So you are right, it is a very helpful tool to use the `over` but it depends what you need it for

Comment: @RaheelHasan Absolutely.

Comment: Which one do you think is faster? MAX() all columns and only 1 column in group by? or all columns in group by with no max()?

Comment: @RaheelHasan  "One test is worth a thousand expert opinions"